# iOS: Is there a way to get the backgroundColor of every element in a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, subclass, objective-c-category

I'm currently trying to create a simple method call in my `ViewController` such as:

```
[self greyscale];
```

Where greyscale is a method in a `UIViewController` category. What I'm trying to do is using recursion and blocks, I'm trying to gather every element in the `ViewController` and get their `backgroundColor` property and then change those values so that it becomes greyScale i.e. `[UIColor colorWithWhite:(0.299*red + 0.587*green + 0.114*blue) alpha:alpha];`

I've tried the following (so far only for uibuttons):

```
- (void)runBlockOnAllSubviews:(SubviewBlock)block {

    block(self.view);
    for (UIViewController* viewController in [self.view subviews]) {
        [viewController runBlockOnAllSubviews:block];
    }
}

- (void)greyscale {

    [self runBlockOnAllSubviews:^(UIView *view) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       [(UIControl *)view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
       [(UIButton *)view setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}];
```

So far setting the background color works, but the problem is I have receiving the current backgroundColor of that element so I can send it to another method that does the "grayscaling" for me, so I can I do something like:

```
[(UIControl *)view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greyScaleWith:view.backgroundColor]];
```

When I tried that it sets it to white because the `"view"'s backgroundColor` is `nil` or `0`;

Is there a better way to access and change the color of every element on a uiview without making it complicated in the initial ViewController? I would like to do this for greyscale, darkerShade, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have two questions here. Ask one per topic. Do you want help with why you get white or do you want help doing this whole process differently?

Comment: If this isn't the most optimal way of doing what I want I would love to learn how to do it much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do with blocks in your code; I don't think there's any particular advantage to using blocks to accomplish your task. Also, your first loop (for (UIViewController* viewController in [self.view subviews])) doesn't make sense, because there are no view controllers as subviews of your view. You can change all the colors with a simple recursive method in a category on UIView. I've included a typedef to define different types of color conversions. My example just converts the colors to light gray or gray, so you should substitute whatever algorithm you want in convertColorForView:conversionType: to accomplish your goals. Here's the .h,

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RDColorConversionType) {
    RDColorConversionTypeGrayScale = 0,
    RDColorConversionTypeDarken,
};

@interface UIView (ColorConversions)

- (void)convertSubviewsBackgroundColor:(RDColorConversionType) type;
```

The .m file,

```
@implementation UIView (ColorConversions)

- (void)convertSubviewsBackgroundColor:(RDColorConversionType) type {
    //[self grayScaleForView:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [self convertColorForView:subview conversionType:type]; // delete this line, and uncomment the one above if you want the view that calls this method to have its background color changed too.
        [subview convertSubviewsBackgroundColor:type];
    }
}


-(void)convertColorForView:(UIView *) view conversionType:(RDColorConversionType) type {
    switch (type) {
        case RDColorConversionTypeGrayScale:
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            break;
        case RDColorConversionTypeDarken:
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            break;
    }

}
```

You would call this method in your view controller like so,

```
[self.view convertSubviewsBackgroundColor:RDColorConversionTypeGrayScale];
```

Comment: Thanks for this rdelmar! I guess I was just trying to call this method from the viewController since I would love to also access the navigation bar from that view controller's parent (if it exists). How could I use this to also access the parent of the view's elements?

Comment: @KingPolygon, I am calling the method from the view controller.  I'm not sure what you mean by "parent of the view's elements".

Comment: sorry for the confusion I meant calling the method on the viewController itself such as [self converSubviews...] that way it I could also check if the ViewController itself has a navigationController as its parentView and also adjust background / bar tint properties for that navigationBar.

Comment: @KingPolygon, you could convert the category to one on UIViewController easily enough. I think the only thing you would need to change would be this: from (UIView *subview in self.subviews) to this: for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)

Comment: Oh awesome! And to get any elements in it's superview, could I use superview inside of subview correct?

Comment: @KingPolygon, I'm not sure whether it will work if you use superview. Try it and see. Whether there is a superview or not (other than the window itself) will depend on your controller hierarchy.